# Siunitx plugin in mathjax and talkyard

Tags: mathjax

I am trying to enable [`siunitx`](https://github.com/burnpanck/MathJax-siunitx) for a (hosted) [talkyard](https://www.talkyard.io/) side and by adding the following to the html header:

```
<script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
 MathJax.Hub.Config({
   extensions: ["tex2jax.js","[siunitx]/siunitx.js"],
   jax: ["input/TeX","output/HTML-CSS"],
   tex2jax: {inlineMath: [["$","$"],["\\(","\\)"]]},
   TeX: {extensions: ["AMSmath.js","AMSsymbols.js", "sinuitx.js"]}
 });
 MathJax.Ajax.config.path['siunitx']  = 'http://rawgit.com/burnpanck/MathJax-siunitx/master/';
 </script>

<script type="text/javascript" async
  src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.4/MathJax.js?config=TeX-MML-AM_CHTML">
</script>
<script>
talkyard.postElemPostProcessor = function(elem) {
  console.log('Telling MathJax to post process elem: ' + elem);
  MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset", MathJax.Hub, elem]);
};
</script>
```

However [rawgit](https://rawgit.com/) seems to be down now and I didn't find another server for it. So how can I enable the `siunitx` extension on a hostet `talkyard` site?